# Differences between BGP(routing protocols) and vpn mpls?

Tags: router, vpn, bgp, wan, mpls-vpn

I am new to networking, so bear with me,

1-I wanted to clear my query: why do we need BGP or any routing protocols if we have vpn or wan technologies like mpls ?

2-Can't we just run bgp between two different sites location to share data?

Thanks

Comment: Remember that routing protocols, like BGP, _do not route_. Routing protocols only share routing information between routers, and a router with no path to a destination will drop packets for that destination. BGP exchanges information with neighboring routers so that a router has paths to more distant destinations than its directly connected networks.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

As @ronmaupin suggests, you are talking about two different things.

Routing protocols exchange routing information so that routers can populate their routing tables.  They have nothing to do with the actual routing (forwarding) of data.

WAN technologies (I'll include MPLS for the sake of argument) are simply logical and/or physical connections between networks.

To give a simple analogy: you can think of WAN technologies as roads between cities.  But you can't use the roads if you don't know where they go to.  Routing protocols are like the road signs that tell you to use this road if you want to go to city A or that road to go to city B